# How to get data from query

Tags: php, session

Here is my code:

```
$user = $_SESSION['uname'];
echo $user;
$output=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT pedia_id FROM users WHERE uname = $user");
echo $output;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM infant_info where pedia_number = $output ORDER BY last_name ASC");
```

It echoes `$user` but not the `$output` and I got an error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Infant\view\InfantInfo_table.php on line 69

Answer (score 1):

you need to put the $user in quotes.

```
"SELECT pedia_id FROM users WHERE `uname` = '".$user."'"
```

also [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php). You need to get the pedia_id from $output and then use it in next query.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($output);
```

now use $row[0] in the next query instead of $output. place it in quotes.

```
$user = $_SESSION['uname'];
echo $user;
$output=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT pedia_id FROM users WHERE uname = '" . $user . "'");
echo $output;  //its mysqli_result object
//Fetch the row from the result
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($output);
echo $row[0];  //this is pedia_id
$pedia_id = $row[0];  //wrap it in quotes if its a string
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM infant_info where pedia_number = $pedia_id ORDER BY last_name ASC");

while($infantRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   //do something here with individual infant_info row
}
```

EDIT : assuming there can be quotes in the string value of $user. in such a case you need to escape that as well. in general sanitizing any value used for forming queries is considered best practice. alternatively you can use [Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: i try your post and i got this error :Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string"

Comment: as i said you need to get the results from mysqli_result object.

Comment: i already did.. here is my code for the result


      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {
       $id = $row['infant_id'];

                echo "<tr style='background-color:#e8e8e8;'>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['middle_name'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['infant_number'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['pedia_number'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
        }

Comment: i added modified snippet from the question.

Comment: you need to run mysqli_fetch_array for both the queries.

Comment: try and share the results.

Comment: what, if $_SESSION['uname'] == "Alex's" ?

Comment: escaping quotes and sanitizing inputs all the time is obviously recommend. but thanks for the tip. i'll add this as edit.